# Disabling StatusCodePages middleware for API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.1, the source for [StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/8893337fb090c523843564a91054996bfcc3cc42/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs#L36-L37)

```
if (!statusCodeFeature.Enabled)
{
    // Check if the feature is still available because other middleware (such as a web API written in MVC) could
    // have disabled the feature to prevent HTML status code responses from showing up to an API client.
    return;
}
```

appears to present the assumption that the API middleware disables the handler, however it does not. Is there a cleaner way to enable the middleware only for MVC requests without a call to `app.UseWhen` and checking the path string, or is this the best approach?

```
app.UseWhen(
    context => !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
    builder => builder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/.../{0}"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's somewhat down to interpretation, but I'd say that comment is just suggesting that something *could* have disabled the feature, but not that anything actually does, by default.

I don't think there's anything obviously cleaner - what you have makes sense but another option would be to use a custom middleware that toggles the feature off. Here's what that might look like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/.../{0}");

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        if (ctx.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var statusCodeFeature = ctx.Features.Get<IStatusCodePagesFeature>();

            if (statusCodeFeature != null && statusCodeFeature.Enabled)
                statusCodeFeature.Enabled = false;
        }

        await next();
    });

    // ...
    app.UseMvc();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right answer for me was to use plain `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` in Startup.cs but vary the handling in the error controller. This allowed me to return plain text content for API errors but retain a friendly view for users.

Startup.cs

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

Error controller:

```
[HttpGet("error/{statusCode:int}")]
public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
{
    var statusCodeFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

    var exceptionDataFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

    // ... Other logging and stuff

    IActionResult actionResult;

    if (statusCodeFeature == null || statusCodeFeature.OriginalPath.StartsWith("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        actionResult = Content($"The request could not be processed: {statusCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;

        actionResult = View();
    }

    return actionResult;
}
```